# Getting Timeout error for Read/Write request in Leshan server

Tags: leshan

[image]

How to remove this error, I don't know from where the issue is happening. Is it happening from server side or client side. How to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Leshan server has a timeout of 5 Sec. The client should acknowledge leshan server for any Conformable request sent within 5 sec, if not leshan server gives timeout.
For better understanding you can use wireshark on leshan server.